# Bone Symmetry works only along X-Axis. But how to make it work along Z-Axis?

Tags: animation, rigging, bones

I am new to rigging in Blender. I watched many rigging tutorial, most of them show how to symmetrize the bone along X-axis, by naming it ".L" or ".R". But my model (a robot arm) require symmetrize bone along Z-axis. I tried to name it ".Top" but it doesn't work.

Does anyone have a clue how to do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symmetrize function works only on X axis.
If you want to copy over the Z axis (Top - Bottom) you can set the 3D cursor in the center of Z symmetry, set the 3D cursor as pivot point, select the Top bones, press Shift D, S, Z, -1, Enter.

Then select the newly created bottom bones, go to Armature menu > Names > Auto names Top/bottom.

Then press F3, search for "batch rename", switch from objects to bones, Find/replace, find ".001.", replace with "."

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, sir!